# How to get rid of string of characters in CString in C++

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, arguments, cstring

The CString type I am talking about is [microsoft's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688%28v=vs.60%29).

I've attempted two methods;

Method 1) using the Remove() and Replace() function found on msdn website, and Visual c++ says `Error:argument of type "const char*" is incompatible with argument of type "wchar_t"`

Specifically my code is:

```
#include <cstring>

CString sTmp= sBody.Mid(nOffset);
CString sFooter= L"https://" + sTmp.Mid(0, nEnd );
sFooter.Remove("amp;");
```

And I don't want to remove a single character at a time because it will get rid of other 'a's.

For some reason, when I convert sFooter to a std::string, random "amp;"s appear in the string that shouldn't be there...

I am converting sFooter to a std::string like this:

```
CT2CA p (sFooter);
string str (p);
```

Method 2) Converting the CString to std::string, then using erase() and remove() to get rid of the "amp;"s

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

sFooter2.erase(std::remove(sFooter2.begin(), sFooter2.end(), "amp;"), sFooter2.end());
```

But Visual studio's output shows this: http://pastebin.com/s6tXQ48N

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using Replace.

`sFooter.Replace(_T("&amp;"), _T(""))`;

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear. Instead of using regular strings you need to use wide strings.

```
sFooter.Remove(L"amp;");
```

Also [according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4931ye.aspx) the `Remove` method only accepts a single character. You'll need to find another way to remove an entire substring.

Comment: When I try that, there's a red line under L, saying `Error:argument of type "const wchar_t*" is incompatible with argument of type "wchar_t"`